# Ajax call to call a Controller give 404 error

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I am using Ajax call to call a Controller method but I am getting this error:
http://localhost:55942/%22GetCalculateAmortizationSchedule%22,%20%22Home%22 404 (Not Found)

This is my Controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetCalculateAmortizationSchedule()
    {
        var data = ......
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:62815/v1/APR/CalculateAmortizationSchedule", data).Result;
        var returnValue = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Dictionary<int, AmItem>>().Result;
        return Content(returnValue.ToString());
    }
```

This is the View code:

```
 <form id="MyForm" method="post">
  ....
   <input type="submit" id="test" value="test" />
   </form>
```

and this is the Ajax code:

```
$('#MyForm').submit(function (e) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCalculateAmortizationSchedule", "Home")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                alert("success");
                console.log(result.data);
                // here in result you will get your data
            },
            error: function (result) {

            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I think problem is this line that cannot find the url:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetCalculateAmortizationSchedule", "Home")',
```

Comment: What does your url like look like if your inspect the source of your page?

Comment: @Kolichikov http://localhost:55942/%22GetCalculateAmortizationSchedule%22,%20%22Home%22

Comment: Looks like you have weird encoding there, try using `@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetCalculateAmortizationSchedule", "Home")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead of URl

url: "/home/GetCalculateAmortizationSchedule"

If you on same controller then do not need to add controller name

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetCalculateAmortizationSchedule")',
```